# JAX RS Resource that proxies requests?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, proxy, jax-rs, server-sent-events

How can I build a JAX RS Resource that proxies requests and responses? -- that is I can forward request and response bodies, possibly changing minor details like headers

Have tried forwarding requests to/from a client within a resource definition, but this does not let me mix server-sent events and regular responses and makes it hard to know if the response changed when it is reencoded with JAX RS.

Answer (score 0):

JAX-RS allows usage of filters to log, change and validate incoming request and outgoing responses, as described in [chapter 6](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/3.1/jakarta-restful-ws-spec-3.1#filters_and_interceptors) of its specification.

If you need to change the incoming request, you must have a `@Provider` that implements `ContainerRequestFilter` interface and then bind this filter to a given rest endpoint.

Let's say that you have to change an incoming request header. You should implement something like this:

```
@jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Provider
public class IncomingFilter implements jakarta.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter {
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext ctx) throws IOException {
        fixHeaders(ctx);
    }

    private void fixHeaders(ContainerRequestContext ctx) {
        // Do your thing
    }
}
```

If you must apply the filter to every request, it should be done. If you have to apply only for some rest endpoints, you must bind it ideally using name binding just like CDI does. Create a name binding annotation such as:

```
@NameBinding
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.Method})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface HeaderAdjusted {}
```

Annotate both provider and endpoint with the name binding and it's ready to go:

```
@Provider
@HeaderAdjusted
public class IncommingFilter (...)

@Path("/")
public class MyEndpointClass {

    @HeaderAdjusted
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Path("hi")
    public String hi() {
        return myFixedHeaderInformationFromContext();
    }
}
```

Please read the whole chapter 6 from spec for more information.